# how can i register a callback for an action client

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the example in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Callback%20Based%20Simple%20Action%20Client) and register feedback and active callbacks to pass to the boost::bind. However, i have trouble finding the proper syntax/way to register them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253860/how-can-i-register-a-callback-for-an-action-client/) by [nvog1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29265/nvog1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrozenCh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29243/frozench/) on 2017-02-05**:
you can post your code or error messages then we can help you more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, basically you just have to repeat the syntax given for the doneCB.  As far as i understood, you need the binder because you cannot use the () operator to indicate if your function has inputs.

The first parameter references your function, the second one to which object the function belongs to. Afterwards, you just need parameters if you have inputs.

Here's n' example how i implemented this.
ac.sendGoal(goal,
boost::bind(&MyNode::doneCb, this, _1, _2),
boost::bind(&MyNode::activeCB,this),
boost::bind(&JacoClient::feedbackCb, this, _1));

If you want more details, you can check out the boost documentation ( it's quite good documented).

---

Originally posted by [Sascha_92](https://answers.ros.org/users/33438/sascha_92/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0